# PHP cURL POST returns Unsupported Media Type

Tags: php, ssl, curl

Currently working with integrating a new e-commerce API ([Swish](https://www.getswish.se)) but having a bit of a struggle. I'm using PHP and cURL in my app to perform a test-connection to their Merchant Simulator. Code looks as follows:

```
$post = array(
    "payeePaymentReference"=> "0123456789",
    "callbackUrl"=> "https://myssldomain.com",
    "payerAlias"=> "4671234768",
    "payeeAlias"=> "1231181189",
    "amount"=> "100", 
    "currency"=> "SEK",
    "message"=> "Kingston USB Flash Drive 8 GB"
);

$ch = curl_init(); 

curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, false); 
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, 'https://mss.swicpc.bankgirot.se/swish-cpcapi/api/v1/paymentrequests/'); 
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSLKEY, 'sslkey.key');
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSLCERT, 'sslcert.crt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, 'cainfo.crt');

$data = curl_exec($ch);

$error = curl_error($ch);

curl_close($ch); 

var_dump($data);
```

Note: the callback-url in the post-array is different. I have a valid, SSL-domain set there as callback URL.

The response i get when proceeding with above code is this:

```
HTTP/1.1 415 Unsupported Media Type
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Accept-Ranges: bytes
ETag: W/"0-1448896356000"
Last-Modified: Mon, 30 Nov 2015 15:12:36 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 0
Date: Sun, 24 Jan 2016 21:07:00 GMT
```

The 3 parts of the SSL-certificate can be found at [Swish's API site](https://www.getswish.se/handel/) if you download the test-tool (Guide Testverktyg). Can anyone please tell me what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: And where do you set `CURLOPT_POST` to 1? You need to set that if you want to send a POST request (I think you want that, as much as I can see `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`).

Comment: @CharlotteDunois Tried it before and just tried it again, but didn't help. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Do you have a curl line (command-line) that works?

Comment: Well, I only get the following error with cURL `error:14094410:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert handshake failure`. There seems to be something wrong with their website.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you post an array directly to the POST, it will transfer as `Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----------------------------` and that's why you are getting this unsupported media type error.

Use `http_build_query` over your array and you should be fine as it will send data as `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

```
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($post));
```